# I get zero value when trying to find the coordinate value of the imageview in android

Tags: android, imageview, coordinates

I Implemented this code for my imageview that is added in the layout. I am getting startY=0.

```
Matrix matrix = iv.getImageMatrix ();
float[] values = new float[];
matrix.getValues(values);
float startY = values[5];
```

I tried

```
 int i=iv.getBottom();
```

this is also returning 0. Can someone help to find the coordinate value of my ImageView in a layout.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `View.getLocationOnScreen()` and/or `View.getLocationInWindow()` is what you're looking for.

Comment: This can be done only on onclick event i want something that fetches the x and y coordinate value of the imageview that is displayed on the screen